# "Always open with" option not saving after reboot

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, restart, reboot

Setting a filetype to always open with a specific application works only until I restart my computer. Macbook Pro Retina under OSX version 10.7.5.

Why?

Comment: Have you tried [rebuilding the Launch Services database](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031215144430486)?

Comment: @LauriRanta I'm getting > Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister \
> -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
-bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister: No such file or directory

Comment: I accidentally linked an older article. Try [the command here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071102084155353).